# How do I set up environment variables for my product in Xcode 4?

Tags: objective-c, xcode4

I just recently move to Xcode 4, now I'm stuck trying to find the executable file (it used to be in the left pane of Xcode 3), anyone know where it is? Since I'm trying to adding a new environment variable to debug my program. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can specify the environment in the Scheme Editor (Product → Edit Scheme), select the Run option in the left column and you’ll see an Arguments tab on the right:

[image: Xcode 4 Scheme Editor]

Comment: I see. I never thought it'll go that far, so that means I keep on looking in the wrong place. Thanx man..