# "Environment Variable is too long" in Xcode 4

Tags: xcode, xcode4, gdb, environment-variables, dyld

I have a Xcode 4 project generated by cmake.

When I build and try to debug on my iOS device (ipod/ipad)

The gdb console prints such message:

```
warning: Environment variable too long, skipping: DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH=/Users/dokinkon/src/gamekit/build_iphone/Samples/IPhoneDemo/bin-iphoneos/Release:/Users/dokinkon/src/gamekit/build_iphone/Dependencies/Source/GameKit/Utils/bin-iphoneos/Release:/Users/dokinkon/src/gamekit/build_iphone/Dependencies/Source/GameKit/AnimKit/bin-iphoneos/Release:/Users/dokinkon/src/gamekit/build_iphone/Dependencies/Source/Blender25/Serialize/BlenderSerialize/bin-iphoneos/Release:/Users/dokinkon/src/gamekit/build_iphone/Dependencies/Source/Blender25/Serialize/BulletFileLoader/bin-iphoneos/Release:/Users/dokinkon/src/gamekit/build_iphone/Dependencies/Source/FreeImage/ZLib/bin-iphoneos/Release:/Users/dokinkon/src/gamekit/build_iphone/Dependencies/Source/FreeType/bin-iphoneos/Release:/Users/dokinkon/src/gamekit/build_iphone/Dependencies/Source/OIS/bin-iphoneos/Release:/Users/dokinkon/src/gamekit/build_iphone/Dependencies/Source/Codecs/bin-iphoneos/Release:/Users/dokinkon/src/gamekit/build_iphone/Dependencies/Source/Lua/lua/bin-iphoneos/Release:/Users/dokinkon/src/gamekit/build_iphone/Dependencies/Source/FreeImage/bin-iphoneos/Release:/Users/dokinkon/src/gamekit/build_iphone/Ogre-1.8/OgreMain/bin-iphoneos/Release:/Users/dokinkon/src/gamekit/build_iphone/bullet/src/BulletDynamics/bin-iphoneos/Release:/Users/dokinkon/src/gamekit/build_iphone/bullet/src/BulletCollision/bin-iphoneos/Release:/Users/dokinkon/src/gamekit/build_iphone/bullet/src/LinearMath/bin-iphoneos/Release:/Users/dokinkon/src/gamekit/build_iphone/Ogre-1.8/RenderSystems/GLES/bin-iphoneos/Release:/Users/dokinkon/src/gamekit/build_iphone/Ogre-1.8/PlugIns/ParticleFX/bin-iphoneos/Release:/Users/dokinkon/src/gamekit/build_iphone/Engine/bin-iphoneos/Release
```

gdb prints these messages continuously such that I can't debug my program.

I'm sure I didn't set DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH.
Maybe xcode4 or cmake can set/unset this environment variable somewhere?

I already tried reset DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH like this answer, but doesn't work
[How do I set up environment variables for my product in Xcode 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5987937/how-do-i-set-up-environment-variables-for-my-product-in-xcode-4)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is your problem or not, but if you set header/framework/library search paths in your target's build settings and hit the recursive checkbox, it'll recursively add every subpath. That can be a huge number of paths (too long a string to fit in an env var). This has caused similar problems for me.

What I really meant to do in that case was to add just one search path for the location of a main header or specific framework or folder of frameworks. Once I made that adjustment, it worked fine.