# Xcode env variables not set

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I downloaded the new Xcode5 preview and have found I cannot build my main project. Everything was ok in `4.6.3`. I am aware that Xcode5 is in beta and should not be discussed in public forums however this question is not specific to `Xcode5`.

The reason the project is not building is some environment variables are not being set
`BUILD_COMPONENTS` is empty
`BUILD_DIR` and `BUILD_ROOT` are not even being set

I can see which variables are set using xcodebuild ShowBuildsettings command

Can anyone tell me where these variables are pulled from for use by Xcode so I can fix the issue

Thanks

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5987937/how-do-i-set-up-environment-variables-for-my-product-in-xcode-4 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5295476/how-to-set-environment-variables-in-iphone-executable-using-xcode-4

Comment: those link are how to add a new one. The issue I have is the standard ones I have mentioned have not been set correctly.

Comment: Then probably the issue is with xcode 5

Comment: Not necessarily, I have this problem with a particular Xcode project (.proj file) others are working OK. I would like to fix this proj file though